# Filtering GridView using Hyperlinks ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a GridView connected to an SQL database, with hyperlinks in the first column, labelled as ID. When this hyperlink is clicked it will take the user to another page with another GridView item on it, connected to a different table in the same Schema.

Is there a way to use the hyperlink text to filter the results on this new GridView table.

Tnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the id from first Page using query string

and for the grid where use this query string in your where clause

eg:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id=0;
    if(Request.QueryString["id"] !=null)
    {
     id=int.parse(Request.QueryString["id"].toSting());
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
            SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString =                  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from table where id="+id;
            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

your page url will be like

**www.Something.com/yourPage.aspx?id=77**